# C# StylusButtonDown Unexpected Call

Tags: c#, stylus-pen

I am developing tablet application where I want to handle StylusButtonDown/Up events to indicate erasing mode. I put those 2 methods into DataInterestMask in StylusHandler but the result is that those two methods are called event if I **dont** press the button on stylus! ButtonDown is called when I touch the screen and ButtonUp when I take it off (Note : ButtonDown /Up is of course also called when the button on stylus is pressed.)
This what I did not expect after reading this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337400
Any ideas how couls this happen?

Comment: Can you show exactly, how are you adding your handler?

Comment: public DataInterestMask DataInterest
    {
    get
            {
                return DataInterestMask.StylusDown |
                       DataInterestMask.Packets |
                       DataInterestMask.StylusUp |
                       DataInterestMask.StylusInRange |
                       DataInterestMask.StylusOutOfRange |
                       DataInterestMask.StylusButtonDown | 
                       DataInterestMask.StylusButtonUp |
                       DataInterestMask.InAirPackets;
            }
        }

Comment: Your DataInterestMask is not so interesting. Can you show, how you add your handlers for event?

Comment: There is just a class StylusHandler : IStylusAsyncPlugin, IStylusSyncPlugin, IDisposable. That has this DataInterestMask field and definition of these methods. AFAIK this is all that is necessary to handle events. You didn't mean the body of handlers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".